# PostgreSQL starts for a few minutes, then fails

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, centos7

I recently moved my PostgreSQL data_directory from `/var/lib/pgsql/data` to `/home/databasepostgre/`. I have followed these steps from

1. $sudo systemctl stop postgresql-9.4.service
2. edit postgresql.conf data_directory to /home/databasepostgre/pgsql/9.4/data
3. $sudo rsync -av /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data /home/databasepostgre/pgsql/9.4/data
4. $su postgres
5. ## psql
6. ## SHOW data_directory; "it shows new directory which is /home/databasepostgre/pgsql/9.4/data"
7. ## systemctl start service

But each time i execute step #6, I always end up with this error :

Job for postgresql-9.4.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service and journalctl -xe for details.

From journalctl -xe the error is as follows:

```
May 11 13:35:04 systemd[1]: postgresql-9.4.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 11 13:35:04 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.4 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-9.4.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql-9.4.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
May 11 13:35:04 systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.4.service entered failed state.
May 11 13:35:04 systemd[1]: postgresql-9.4.service failed.
```

Can anyone please help me? This is a production server and I still cannot find the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you check the PG logs probably in : /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log or /var/log/postgresql/ or /var/log/pgsql    :::: what it says

Comment: i have custom log in my /home directory and all it said : terminating connection due to administrator command, the database system is shutting down